# Loopback 3 & Angular 2 generation of /reset-password endpoint unrealiable

Tags: arrays, angular, authentication, loopbackjs

We are building an application that so far has a simple user management implementation. This question relates to the built-in password resetting functionality of Loopback v3. User management is being worked on a model derived from the built-in `User`, and it is called `MyCustomUser`

Each time code changes are pushed into a GitHub repo, we have Jenkins build a Docker container, and inside of it run `npm install` then `lb-sdk` (with suitable parameters) then `ng build --env=prod` and finally `node .`. After this happens, the application runs normally, BUT:

- When performing the same deployment commands locally (on my own linux laptop), the API endpoints `/MyCustomUsers/reset` and `/MyCustomUsers/reset-password` are created (i.e. they are visible and manipulable via the Strongloop Explorer)
- When the deployment is run by Jenkins in the Docker container, only one of the two API endpoints is created, `/MyCustomUsers/reset`. God only knows where the other endpoint, `/MyCustomUsers/reset-password`, ends up.

Obviously, all deployments are run against the same codebase (i.e. the same commit ID of the GitHub repo). It is bewildering how the service behaves perfectly on localhost but not on the cloud-based docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are running two different versions of the Loopback-Angular2-SDK. From what I've understood the SDK for Angular2 is still in heavy beta and not yet ready for production. However this doesn't excuse the difference, but it really sounds like two different versions.

We are using the same build-flow as you, are your package.json identical when it comes to @mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder?

The guys working with the SDK-generator are really good at responding in their issue-section, would recommend asking there otherwise.

Comment: `package.json` is also checked into the GitHub repo, so its deployment is identical everywhere.

Comment: Was more of thinking of your local computer running an older version while you have the latest on your prods. It's easy to type ^ in front of version in package.json. ^^

Comment: Right, but not a chance. I haven't modified `package.json` in any way. What's being read in localhost is also being read from the docker container.

Comment: That's not what I insinuate, doing an npm ls -depth=0 locally and in container, do both lists look identical? package,json could be precisely the same but still you can run different modules depending wheter you use ^ or not (depends on time when you ran install).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the remote docker was running node 6.9.2 and npm 3.10.9, whereas I was running node 6.10.3 and npm 3.10.10. After making the docker instance run the same versions as I had locally and deploying the `package.json` along with its `npm-shrinkwrap.json`, the endpoint was correctly generated.